# python3における0の省略

Tags: python, python3

python3で

```
a = 0x00001234ABCD
```

のような変数を16進数で出力すると

```
1234ABCD
```

となってしまいます。
０を省略させずにそのまま表示するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
それともpython2でしかできないのでしょうか？

```
a = 0x00001234ABCD

print(hex(a))
0x1234abcd

print(format(a,"x"))
1234abcd
```

Comment: 「0が省略される」というのは、`0x` の部分のことでしょうか、それとも先頭の `0000` の部分のことでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！0xではなく先頭の0000のことです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

数を出力する際先頭にゼロを付けるには、[`str.format()`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) などのフォーマット関数を使う方法があります。

```
>>> a = 0x00001234ABCD
>>> print("0x{:012x}".format(a))
0x00001234abcd
>>> print("0x{:012X}".format(a))
0x00001234ABCD
```

Comment: ０を後付けするしか方法はないのでしょうか？入力されたものをそのまま出力したいのですが。

Comment: 整数として扱っている以上内部的には単なる2進数であって入力時の状態を覚えていないので、今与えられている情報のみからだと 0 を後付けするしか無いように思います。文字列として扱うのであれば別ですが……。Python 2 だとできた、とのことですが、その際はどのようなコードをお使いだったのでしょうか？

Comment: あ、いえpython2ならできるのかという意味でした！

Comment: なるほど。16進数を整数として保存する際に桁数の情報は忘れられてしまうため、Python 2 であろうと 3 であろうと、出力する際に桁数を指定して 0 を後付けするのが自然だと感じます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！とても参考になりました。

Answer (score 3):

n進数の接頭辞(`0x`)を自動で付与させたい場合は`format`関数のフォーマット指定`{}`で`#`を含める方法がありますが、桁数は接頭辞も考慮して指定する必要があります。

```
print('HEX: {:012X}'.format(0x00001234ABCD))
print('HEX: {:#014X}'.format(0x00001234ABCD))
```

結果

```
HEX: 00001234ABCD
HEX: 0X00001234ABCD
```